# how to store api fetched data in indexeddb using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want fetch data from api and store that data locally. Api response data are of huge amount(in thousands). Basically I'll have to develop e-commerce website so when i refresh page or go to next page data should not disappear. Can anyone tell me how should i do? I thought of using indexedDB but unable to add api response data into it. Any other approach or piece of code for storing api data in indexedDB in reactjs will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I faced a similar problem while i was developing a chat app, so I used firebase and enabled persistence and they did all the other work for me ( like storing data in indexedDb )

Answer (score 1):

You could use something called LocalStorage. This saves the data in the user's browser.
[Look into it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Are you sure it will be equally performent as indexddb

Comment: Ya but it has limited storage. As i mentioned there are huge amount of data.

Comment: @VibhaSingh you should definitely try firestore ( by firebase )